# How can I access an XML-Attribute of a specific node in Twig (Symfony)?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an xml like that:

```
<item>
  <domain>
    <currentPrice currency="EUR">17.9</currentPrice>
  </domain>
</item>
```

I can render the value of 17.9 in Twig using

```
item.domain.currentPrice
```

But how can I access the attribute "currency" to render it?

```
item.domain.currentPrice['currency']
```

is not working. Then I'm getting:

```
Key "curreny" in object (with ArrayAccess) of type "SimpleXMLElement" does not exist
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the currency property value through attributes() method:

```
{{ xml.domain.currentPrice.0.attributes.currency }}
```

as you would do that in php:

```
$xml->domain->currentPrice[0]->attributes()->currency;
```

Actually twig makes this transformation from twig-code to php-code and php-code is executed eventually.

You can scrutinize API of [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.ph) to understand what methods and properties you can use.